# Gigabyte H110M-S2PV-CF (DDR4) not booting, needs CMOS reset to boot again

Tags: motherboard, cmos

Once in 2 or 3 days, ***I need to reset CMOS of my new PC*** just to boot. Otherwise it just won't boot. Even power lights won't light up.

I tried many things to solve this. Here is the list.

***1. I checked every other parts, even GPU with another PC and it worked just fine.***

***2. Updated BIOS but problem occurred again.***

***3. Reset BIOS to default. Removed CMOS battery. worked for few days but again with this boot problem.***

I'm facing this problem from the time I bought this PC and it's been a month. At first I thought maybe I had something wrong setting up the PC and tried to fix it as I described before. I even replaced that Gigabyte H110M-S2PV-CF (DDR4) motherboard. It was fine for a week. and again with this booting problem again!

Most heavy thing I do with this PC is using Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015. I also use othe Adobe Products like Illustrator, Photoshop, After Effects, In Design and sometimes Lightroom too.
Never Installed any game before.
And I updated every single driver as well.
I'm using Windows 10.

here's my specs,

- Motherboard: Gigabyte H110M-S2PV-CF (DDR4) [rev. 1.0]
- Processor  : Intel i5 6500
- RAM        : Vengeance® LPX 8GB DDR4 DRAM 2400MHz x 2 = 16GB in total
- PSU        : Thermaltake 550 watt light power
- GPU        : Zotac Nvidia GT 730 2GB GDDR5
- Storage    : 1TB Toshiba
- Display    : Dell S2216H 21.5-Inch Full HD LED Monitor

[note: my motherboard supprots 2133MHz RAM but I installed 2400MHz ones.]

I'm thinking about buying a new motherboard. But it would be really helpful to know the exact problem. Because I'm losing my trust in "Gigabyte".

Answer (score 1):

I was suggested from another forum to change CMOS battery. Temporarily works... But it occurred again and again... Specially after a bit heavy use like rendering or mining... My best bet is it might be the RAM. It's a 100 series chipset, means it's for 6th gen Intel CPU. and 6th gen can't support 2400MHz RAM. It downclocks to 2133MHz. For some reason system might fail to downclock it and the problem occurs. I've a friend who has the same motherboard with DDR3 and he never ran into this problem. So I changed H110 to B250. Which officially supports 2400MHz RAM and I never faced this problem again.